# SVN Permissions

Tags: svn

I have a repo that I have checked out to my local machine. The original permissions are svn:svn.
When I do an update, the ones on the server show me as the owner instead of svn. There is a hook that updates the webserver, I dont know how important that is.
How do I keep the permissions the same (svn) throughout the process?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question isn't terribly clear, but it sounds like you have a post-commit hook that is doing a check-out on the server? If yes, then it depends on how you're updating the repository. To quote the doc:

> Subversion executes hooks as the same
>   user who owns the process that is
>   accessing the Subversion repository.
>   In most cases, the repository is being
>   accessed via a Subversion server, so
>   this user is the same user as whom the
>   server runs on the system.

If you're running `svnserve`, then the hooks will execute as you. If you're running the Apache `mod_svn`, then the hooks will run as the Apache user (assuming that it isn't you).

As long as your webserver directory is writable by you and any other SVN user, this shouldn't cause a problem. However, it would make me uncomfortable.